# merge multiple data frames by multiple columns, Pandas, Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to merge multiple data frames in the sequence of df3 - df2 - df1. `df3` and `df2` are merged first by `df3(id, Feature 1)` on `df2(id, Feature 1)`. However then, `df2(id, Feature 2)` and `df1(id, Feature 2)` are merged together. The output would look like:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
    'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    'Feature1': ['K', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'I'],
    'Feature2': ['L', 'N', 'F', 'H', 'J']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2'])

data2 = {
    'id': ['1', '2', '6', '7', '8'],
    'Feature1': ['K', 'M', 'O', 'Q', 'S'],
    'Feature2': ['L', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'T']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2'])

data3 = {
    'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11'],
    'Feature1': ['K', 'M', 'O', 'Q', 'S','X','Y','Z','W','P'],
    'Feature2': ['B', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J','O', 'Q', 'S','X','Y'],
    'Feature3': [12, 13, 14, 'K', 'M','S', 'Q',15, 16, 17,]}


df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2','Feature3'])
```

`df1`, `df2`, and `df3` are shown in the figure above.

Could I ask how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
In [114]: df3.merge(df2, on=['id','Feature1'], how='left').merge(df1, left_on=['id','Feature2_y'], right_on=['id','Feature2'], how='left') 
Out[114]: 
   id Feature1_x Feature2_x Feature3 Feature2_y Feature1_y Feature2
0   1          K          B       12          L          K        L
1   2          M          D       13          N          C        N
2   3          O          F       14        NaN        NaN      NaN
3   4          Q          H        K        NaN        NaN      NaN
4   5          S          J        M        NaN        NaN      NaN
5   7          X          O        S        NaN        NaN      NaN
6   8          Y          Q        Q        NaN        NaN      NaN
7   9          Z          S       15        NaN        NaN      NaN
8  10          W          X       16        NaN        NaN      NaN
9  11          P          Y       17        NaN        NaN      NaN
```